# dbus-laauch failed caused by the child process exited

Tags: cron, python, display, d-bus, libnotify

I want a python script to send notification. The script can be run successfully and show what I want. but crontab did not boot it in right way.

the following is the the code refer to the libnotify

```
def SendMessage(title, message):
    pynotify.init("ChinaBank")
    notice = pynotify.Notification(title,message)
    notice.show()
    return
```

what I did in crontab is

```
* * * * * display=`/home/li/script/FetchDisplay.sh` && export DISPLAY=$display && /home/li/projects/fetch-data/EuroForex.py 2>/home/li/error
```

Here, the FetchDisplay.sh is to get the display as following:

```
#!/bin/bash 

if [ "$DISPLAY" != "" ]; then
        echo $DISPLAY
        exit
fi

if ["$USER" = "" ]; then
        USER=`whoami`
fi

pinky -fw | awk -v user=$USER 'NF == 6 {if($1 == user) {print $6}}' | awk 'NR==1{print $0}
```

the error output is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/li/projects/fetch-data/EuroForex.py", line 43, in <module>
    SendMessage("Please be ready to sell", str(SellData))  
  File "/home/li/projects/fetch-data/EuroForex.py", line 15, in SendMessage
    notice.show()
glib.GError: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=970be6bbf9ff49009918057c308cf56e --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1
```

I know the DISPLAY is **`：0`**， through the command

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

therefore, I test the gnome-screensaver-command with it.

```
* * * * *  export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver-command --lock 2>/home/li/screenerror
```

Unfortunately, it did not work, and the output is

```
** Message: Failed to get session bus: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=970be6bbf9ff49009918057c308cf56e --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1
```

I thought it is the problem of DISPLAY, but the variable DISPLAY is correct. Could you tell what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the answer from here.
[Update Pidgin IM status on Ubuntu using cron](http://earlruby.org/2008/08/update-pidgin-status-using-cron/)

cron run in its own environment, therefore, we have to find the variables DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS, XAUTHORITY, and DISPLAY.  I followed the instruction and succeeded to set the variables.

My script can work now!